# C# version of Javascript Date.getTime()

Tags: c#, javascript

What is the best way in c# to get the same result of javascript date.gettime() call?

> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
private int GetTime()
{
   var time = (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
   return (int)(time.TotalMilliseconds + 0.5);
}
```

Comment: This worked but there was some typos.  Forgot a ; on second to last line, plus you forgot a "new" on st=DateTime.  Once I added those, it solved my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: The + 0.5 is a quick way to round up when you convert to a whole number :)

Comment: @pratapk is it possible that rounding the result (+0.5) cause some inaccuracy  in the result ?

Comment: Casting to int is not enough due to the int is kept on 32 bits, but the total miliseconds will be larger than the 32 bit range. So it is better to cast it to `long`

Answer (score 23):

Since JavaScript time is **with respect to UTC**, I think you will need something like this:

```
var st = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var t  = (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - st);
// t.TotalMilliseconds
```

Now you can use the `TotalMilliseconds` property of the `Timespan`.

Answer (score 10):

The correct implementation (assuming the current time) is as follows:

```
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
long ts = (long)((utcNow - epoch).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 6):

The Java and JavaScript Date.getTime() methods return the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

Since .NET 
represents dates in Ticks (1 Tick = 0.1 nanoseconds or 0.0001 milliseconds) since 1 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT, we must use a 
conversion formula where 621355968000000000 is the offset between the base dates in Ticks and 10000 the number of Ticks per 
Millisecond.

```
Ticks = (MilliSeconds * 10000) + 621355968000000000
MilliSeconds = (Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000
```

Comment: Thanks; works really nice when passing new Date().getTime() from Javascript to server... just do new DateTime(long.Parse(timeSpan)*10000 + 621355968000000000);

Answer (score 4):

I guess this will do the trick :)

```
public double MilliTimeStamp(DateTime TheDate)
        {
            DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            DateTime d2 = TheDate.ToUniversalTime();
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);

            return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
```

Comment: `TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);` can be simplified to `TimeSpan ts = d2 - d1;`

Answer (score 3):

Now in C# you can use built-in function:

```
new DateTimeOffset(Your_DateTime_Variable_Here).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
```

So the sample code would be:

```
var dateToUse = DateTime.Now;
var javaGetTimeValue = new DateTimeOffset(dateToUse).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(DateTime.Now - new DateTime (1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: It should be `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)`.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's javascript that's weirdly zero-based, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer returns an int which is incorrect. It has to be Int64 or long. This is just rewriting the correct answer provided by Matt Johnson-Pint (and edited by Adaptabi) as one line. Please accept Matt Johnson-Pint's answer. I checked it against actual javascript new Date().getTime() in the console to verify it returns the same number.

```csharp
long JavascriptGetTime()
{
    return (long)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method based off [Enigma State's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134246/3103633)

```
public static Int64 GetJavascriptTimeStamp(this DateTime dt)
{
    var nineteenseventy = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    var timeElapsed = (dt.ToUniversalTime() - nineteenseventy);
    return (Int64)(timeElapsed.TotalMilliseconds + 0.5);
}
```

To use it for the current time:

`var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.GetJavascriptTimeStamp();`

Answer (score 0):

```
private static ulong GetTime()
{
    const long INIT_DATA_TICKS = 621355968000000000; // 1.1.1970 in ticks
    const double ROUNDINGS_FIX = 0.5;
    TimeSpan dTicks = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - INIT_DATA_TICKS);
    return (ulong)(dTicks.TotalMilliseconds + ROUNDINGS_FIX);
}
```

DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() use intern DateTime.UtcNow