# Explanation for Timespan Differences Between C# and JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime

This is based on [Computing milliseconds since 1970 in C# yields different date than JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22081128/1346943) and [C# version of Javascript Date.getTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8134170/1346943).

For all of these calculations, assume they are being done in Central Standard Time, so 6 hours behind UTC (this offset will come up again later).

I understand that JavaScript `Date` objects are based on the Unix Epoch (Midnight on Jan 1, 1970). So, if I do:

```
//remember that JS months are 0-indexed, so February == 1
var d = new Date(2014,1,28);
d.getTime();
```

My output will be:

> 1393567200000

Which represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch. That's all well and good. In the linked questions, people were asking about translating this functionality into C# and the "naive" implementation usually looks something like this:

```
//the date of interest in UTC
DateTime e = new DateTime(2014, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
//the Unix Epoch
DateTime s = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
//the difference between the two
TimeSpan t = (e - s);
var x = t.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Which produces output:

> 1393545600000

That's a difference of 21,600,000 milliseconds, or 6 hours: the exact offset from UTC for the time zone in which these calculations were done.

To get the C# implementation to match the JavaScript, this is the implemenation:

```
//DateTimeKind.Unspecified
DateTime st=new DateTime(1970,1,1);
//DateTimeKind.Unspecified
DateTime e = new DateTime(2014,2,28);
//translate e to UTC, but leave st as is
TimeSpan t= (e.ToUniversalTime()-st);
var x = t.TotalMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Which will give me output matching the JavaScript output:

> 1393567200000

What I have yet to find is an explanation for why we leave the `DateTime` representing the Unix Epoch with a `DateTimeKind` of `Unspecified` to be able to match JavaScript. Shouldn't we get the correct result using `DateTimeKind.Utc`? What detail am I not understanding? This is a purely academic question for me, I'm just curious about why this works this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you correctly point out, [`.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns *"the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC."*

Which means that `.getTime` is (as you noticed) including the offset from UTC in the calculation.

In order to make the C# code reflect this, the time you're subtracting from *must* include time zone information, while 1 January 1970 00:00:00 *must* be a UTC time.

This might be easier to understand with a few examples. Given:

```
DateTime e = new DateTime(2014, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime s = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

1. `e - s` is incorrect because `s` is not a UTC time.
2. `e.ToUniversalTime() - s.ToUniversalTime()` is incorrect because `e` no longer includes the offset from UTC (like the calculation in JavaScript does)
3. `e.ToUniversalTime() - s` **is** correct because we're using the UTC time *and* the time we're subtracting includes the offset from UTC.

This was easier for me to see when I dealt with `DateTime.Ticks` directly:

```
e.Ticks // 635291424000000000
s.Ticks // 621355968000000000

e.Ticks - s.Ticks // 13935456000000000 ("naive" implementation)
e.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - s.Ticks // 13935636000000000 (correct output)
```

Again, the last example meets all of our requirements. The Unix epoch is in UTC, while the time we're dealing with still has its original offset.

Comment: Ah, the key point I wasn't comprehending is that `getTime()` takes time zone into consideration. That makes sense. I was under the impression that ALL JS date calculations were UTC-based.

Comment: @ledbutter: It was a head scratcher for me too when I read through it.  Thanks for a good question :)

Comment: `getTime` doesn't take the time zone into account.  In the example code here, it's the `new Date` constructor that does.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that JavaScript Date objects are based on the Unix Epoch (Midnight on Jan 1, 1970).

Yes, they are.  Internally, it's just a number of milliseconds from the epoch.  But when you call the date constructor, or look at the output from `.toString()`, it is using the local time of where the code is running.

If you want the input to be specified in UTC, then you have to use a different incantation:

```
var ts = Date.UTC(2014,1,28);  // returns a numeric timestamp, not a Date object

var dt = new Date(ts);         // if you want a date object

var s = dt.toUTCString();      // if you want the output to be in UTC
```

Comment: Does that mean your first line of code is a different "moment in time" to the original Javascript of the OP (which called getTime) ? If the numeric timestamps are different, then surely they are not the same "moment in time".

Comment: That's right. If the OP's time zone is indeed US Central Time, then that's a different point in time than one that's created using the same values but with respect to UTC.