# SaaS Application and timezones

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timezone, multi-tenant, saas

I have a multi tenant asp.net application. In it each user can set their timezone. However often users log in from browsers where the timezone is different to the preference they have set in my asp.net solution. I want to know, the best practise, should I always force the user to change his computer's timezone to that of his preference in my asp.net application 
OR
Should I not bother and let him be in whichever timezone he is in? Any advice on the best practise or convention on how the big sites such as salesforce and others operate will be very helpful.

Tx

Comment: IMHO, if you ask users to _set something in your application_ then the expectation is that it's _persisted in your application_ (not theirs or any client they use - browser/s, device/s, etc).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can save user preferences like timezone and show in the UI. If the user has no preference, use the UI culture to format the data for display in the UI.

Always store date times in db as UTC format and show in the UI based on the configuration or the current locale.

The JavaScript datetime formats are different from the C# formatting.

Please refer 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx

And, http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096571/explanation-for-timespan-differences-between-c-sharp-and-javascript&ei=30ovNWzN&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=918&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1485879489&sig=AF9NedmhETXDK0ppwa-fSly3Hmy58wdNaw

HTH